# Поддержка Arch Linux ноутбуков трансформеров

Tags: linux, драйвер, железо, archlinux, hp

Призываю всех гуру линукса(арча)!

Купил этого красавчика https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/65669ef3c84f1b80/156-noutbuk-hp-envy-x360-15-cp0011ur-serebristyj/

Поставил Arch, и начали возникать мелкие проблемы которые хотелось бы решить:

1)Если перевернуть крышку(в винде это был режим планшета) клавиатура по-прежнему  работает как и тачпад(в винде отключалось работал только экран).

2)BANG & OLUFSEN звук, качество стало ниже как и громкость.

3)Есть ли какой-нибудь аналог AMD панели для калибровки цвета, яркости и тд?

На борту:
Arch Linux
Cinnamon
LightDM

Молю, подскажите куда копать чтобы все завелось как надо.
Желательно провернуть все под Cinnamon, но буду рад любым решениям.

Comment: поставь гном3. он поддерживает поворот экрана, есть регулятор яркости и калибровка цвета, громкость можно добавить в дополнительных настройках. насчет качества - можно попробовать переключить на 48 кгц в конфигах, но скорее всего он звучит как есть, а на винде стоит какой-то програмный "улучшатель". блокировать клавиатуру при перевороте - надо будет писать скрипты

Comment: Слышал про Gnome3 и эти плюшки, может есть возможность подтянуть их без самого DE как либы?

Comment: Не думаю что кто-то будет тянуть тяжёлые штуки из третьего